# Vue 3 Composition API Array prop won't update in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest, vuex, vue-composition-api

I have read several reporting similar issues, but it seems my case is more specific, let me explain.

I have 3 components (ComponentA, ComponentB and ComponentC).

`ComponentA` fetches the data from API and then renders `ComponentB`, like this:

```
<ComponentB
    v-for="something in dataFromApi"
    :key="something.id"
    :array-prop="filterList(something.id)"
></ComponentB>
```

`ComponentB` accepts the following prop:

```
props: {
    arrayProp: Array,
},
```

This array is expected to be manipulated in ComponentB. So in setup() we have things like:

```
<template>
    <ComponentC
        :another-array-prop="arrayToPassToComponentC"
        @on-item-add:="onItemAdd"
    ></ComponentC>
</template>

setup (props) {

const arrayRef = reactive(props.arrayProp)

// This function is triggered when ComponentC emits onItemAdd event
function onItemAdded (id) {
    // pushing this to arrayRef will add new element to arrayRef
    arrayRef.push({id, label: '', value: ''})

}

function onSubmit() {
    triggerPutApiRequestInVuexStore().then(() => {
        // this function sends GET request to get updated items from DB
        fetchInitialArray()
        // when this fetch is DONE, it should update the arrayProps and propagate it all the way to ComponentC
        // Here is the problem. The props do update, but my Ref does not, so ComponentC does not get the updated props.
    }
}

return {
    arrayToPassToComponentC: arrayRef
 }
}
```

And then sends it to `ComponentC`:

```
<ComponentC
    :another-array-prop="arrayToPassToComponentC"
    @on-item-add:="onItemAdd"
></ComponentC>
```

The `onItemAdd` is an emitted event from `ComponentC`, on a button press.

**PROBLEM:**

When I press the button the callback `onItemAdd` triggers. I then send PUT API request to DB to update my values. After that is successful, I send a GET request to fetch the new values from DB and update my view. The problem is that the GET request needs to update the array in ComponentA and it needs to propagate all the way to ComponentC.

Issue appears in `ComponentB`, where the `const arrayRef = reactive(props.arrayProp)` does not receive the updated props. If I would pass to `ComponentC` just the prop itself, it would update correctly, but this is not the behavior that I want, since I need to manipulate the array in `ComponentB` and the changes need to be reflected in `ComponentC` (that `push` method in `onItemAdd` for example).

If I would do props.arrayProp.push(), this would not reflect change in `ComponentC`, since `props.arrayProp` is obviously not `reactive`.

The problem is that I need the IDs from DB (DB generates its own unique IDs, not what client sends. Client generates UUID just for its own purpose, to be able to track which element was clicked, etc.). If I handle adding / removing / changing elements on Client, users will need to first refresh the entire page, since the IDs won't match with backend and therefore updates won't be successful until refresh. Upon refresh, as expected, the ComponentA re-fetches the data from backend, so IDs are correct and it works. But this is a nuisance for UX.

NOTE: Code is abbreviated for simplicity purposes.

Comment: Just for simplicity I would suggest you using vuex (which I guess you are using in your application, since it's tagged). As you have 3 components interacting with & using the same data you could use a store module. Is that possible?

Comment: It is indeed, and I use vuex in this case too @nonNumericalFloat. But in this case, the ComponentC is actually a Table component. And the issue occurs when I emit `onItemAdd` from that TableComponent.. to the ComponentB.

Comment: `onItemAdd` should spawn an empty new Row in Table.

Comment: Please, provide complete https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It needs to be short but _complete_. Currently some parts are missing and it's unclear what's going on. The comment says, "it should update the arrayProps" but there's no "arrayProps". Is it "arrayProp"? Then it's unclear what this means. arrayProp is a prop that was passed from A, it's readonly by nature. Shouldn't it be arrayRef instead?